# Highlight One Item in a List at any given time (Index 0 by default)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, highlight

Sorry for the horrible title, I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to word this problem. By default I want the first item in my list to be highlighted and others to be highlighted when the mouse is over them. This works fine and I was curious how I am able to remove the highlight of that initial item when another is highlighted, I know I need to handle the state within my parent component (List) but I cannot figure it out.

This is my list item that contains some basic state management to show whether the given item is highlighted or not.

```
export default function Item ({ title, onClick, selected, i }) {
  const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState(false)

  return (
    <ListItem
      i={i}
      key={title}
      selected={selected}
      onClick={onClick}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHighlight(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHighlight(false)}
      // i === 0 && no other item is highlighted (need to get this state from the list component)
      highlight={highlight || i === 0}
    >
      {title}
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

Parent component that takes in a 'list' and maps each item in that list to the above component (Item):

```
export default function List ({ list, onClick, selected, render }) {s
  return (
    <div>
      {render ? (
        <ListContainer>
          {list.map((item, i) => (
            <Item
              i={i}
              key={item.title}
              title={item.title}
              onClick={() => onClick(item.title)}
              selected={selected(item.title)}
            />
          ))}
        </ListContainer>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is a [Gyazo link](https://gyazo.com/7a2ac3638273fd64ece8bb39f9368737) that shows the current implementation, what I want to achieve is for that initial item to no longer be highlighted when the mouse has entered another item where the index does not equal 0.

Comment: which means no item will be highlighted when user cursor will go out of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lift your highlight state to parent List component

```js
function List ({ list, onClick, selected, render }) {
  const [highlightIndex, setHighlightIndex] = setState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      {render ? (
        <ListContainer>
          {list.map((item, i) => (
            <Item
              i={i}
              key={item.title}
              title={item.title}
              onClick={() => onClick(item.title)}
              selected={selected(item.title)}
              highlightIndex={highlightIndex}
              setHighlightIndex={setHighlightIndex}
            />
          ))}
        </ListContainer>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}

function Item ({ title, onClick, selected, i, highlightIndex, setHighlightIndex }) {
  return (
    <ListItem
      i={i}
      key={title}
      selected={selected}
      onClick={onClick}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightIndex(i)}
      highlight={i === highlightIndex}
    >
      {title}
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css

```css
ul:not(:hover) li:first-of-type,
ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

the first one will be highlighted while not hovered, and the other will be highlighted when hovered and "cancel" the first one.

Presuming the selected one will go to the top of the list.