# select classes with same "ClassName"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

So, what I am trying to achieve is selecting all className that contain "list"

Then whenever one is clicked, it becomes "list active", when clicked next, the "active" is removed from the current list and goes to the next one.
something like this
first I want to select all the list classes

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
```

then

```
function activeList() {
    list.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove("active"));
    this.classList.add("active");
   }
```

then I want to add a listener to all "list classes"

```
list.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", activeList));
```

The problem is this approach does not work on react. any suggestion?

Comment: it's react, we don't wanna do like that

Comment: what's the way to do it?

Comment: posting an answer, please wait

Comment: This direct DOM manipulation approach is fundamentally not how React works.  React is a MV* framework, in which you create a data model, bind/wire it to a view, and then all updates are managed in the data model, to which the view reacts.  You might do well to spend a bit of time with some React tutorials to understand idiomatic patterns-- direct DOM manipulation in React is almost always an antipattern.

Comment: are the elements with classname 'list' are in single parent and scattered around everywhere?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html: start here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight One Item in a List at any given time (Index 0 by default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152690/highlight-one-item-in-a-list-at-any-given-time-index-0-by-default)

Comment: also: [Add active class to li items in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586591/add-active-class-to-li-items-in-react)